# What does $\textrm{soc}$ stand for?

Tags: notation, terminology

I'm reading something where for an algebra $A$, there is a claim that the unique minimal, two-sided nonzero ideal is $\operatorname{soc}(A)$.

What does $\mathrm{soc}$ stand for and mean in this context? Google just redirects me to abbreviations of "Society" or "Social."

In group theory I know it stands for the subgroup generated by minimal nontrivial normal subgroups, but I don't know what word it stands for there either.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socle_(mathematics)#Socle_of_a_module

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Thanks.

Comment: Are you reading Quiver Hecke Algebras?